# Отображение окон в QStackedWidget и использовании динамических виджетов

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qstackedwidget

Это код программы. Будьте так добры помочь в оптимизации и интересует ответ на несколько вопросов:

1. Как мне при нажатии на кнопку `edit` в **settings.ui** узнать, в каком `groupbox`'е она находится.
2. Как создать переменную в классе `MainWindow`, в которой будут данные ведённые в `textinput`, который находится в классе `Settings_l`.
3. Как сохранить дизайн, который мы изменяем в *Python* файле во время использования (например, создание дополнительных `groupbox`'ов)

**logick.py**

```py
class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        loadUi("main.ui", self)
        
        self.settings_hm.clicked.connect(self.setting)


    def setting(self):
        settings = Settings_l()
        widget.addWidget(settings)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex() + 1)



class Delete(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Delete, self).__init__()


        loadUi("delete.ui", self)
        

        self.podtvergdenie.clicked.connect(self.podtvergdenies)
        self.otmena.clicked.connect(self.otmens)
            

    def podtvergdenies(self):
        pass

    def otmens(self):
        self.close()    


class Settings_l(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Settings_l, self).__init__()
        loadUi("settings.ui", self)
        

        self.home_set.clicked.connect(self.Home)
        self.deleten.clicked.connect(self.delete)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.new)

    def Home(self):
        mainwindow = MainWindow()
        widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex() + 1)

    def delete(self):
        self.delete_rab = Delete()
        self.delete_rab.resize(280, 175)
        self.delete_rab.setFixedWidth(280)
        self.delete_rab.setFixedHeight(175)
        self.delete_rab.setWindowTitle('Удаление')
        self.delete_rab.show()

    def new(self):
        self.groupBox_2 = QGroupBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.groupBox_2.setMinimumSize(QSize(411, 251))
        self.groupBox_2.setMaximumSize(QSize(411, 251))
        self.groupBox_2.setCheckable(False)
        self.groupBox_2.setStyleSheet(u"border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;\n"
"border-radius: 10;")
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")



        self.save_people_2 = QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.save_people_2.setGeometry(QRect(290, 200, 86, 31))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.save_people_2.setFont(font)
        self.save_people_2.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.save_people_2.setText("Save")
        self.save_people_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #50DD6E;"
            "color: white;"
            "border-radius: 7;")
        self.save_people_2.setObjectName("save_people_2")

        self.edit_2 = QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.edit_2.setGeometry(QRect(190, 200, 86, 31))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.edit_2.setFont(font)
        self.edit_2.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.edit_2.setText("Edit")
        self.edit_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #4E9CFD;"
            "color: white;\n"
            "border-radius: 7;")
        self.edit_2.setObjectName("edit_2")

        self.uzn_2 = QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.uzn_2.setGeometry(QRect(35, 203, 27, 27))
        self.uzn_2.setText(None)
        self.uzn_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Images/383085-32.png"))
        self.uzn_2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.uzn_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;")
        self.uzn_2.setObjectName("uzn_2")

        self.sep_2 = QFrame(self.groupBox_2)
        self.sep_2.setGeometry(QRect(30, 180, 351, 2))
        self.sep_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.sep_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.sep_2.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: #FDD2BF;"
            "border: 1px solid #FDD2BF;")
        self.sep_2.setObjectName("sep_2")



        self.pdk_2 = QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pdk_2.setGeometry(QRect(40, 130, 161, 21))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pdk_2.setFont(font)
        self.pdk_2.setText("Посл. дата отд.: ")
        self.pdk_2.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;"
            "border: None;")
        self.pdk_2.setObjectName("pdk_2")



        self.pdk_edit_2 = QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pdk_edit_2.setGeometry(QRect(200, 130, 171, 26))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pdk_edit_2.setFont(font)
        self.pdk_edit_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;"
            "border-radius: 10;"
            "color: white;"
            "padding-left: 7px;"
            "padding-right: 7px;")
        self.pdk_edit_2.setObjectName("pdk_edit_2")




        self.dk_2 = QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.dk_2.setGeometry(QRect(40, 90, 161, 21))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.dk_2.setFont(font)
        self.dk_2.setText("Дата контракта: ")
        self.dk_2.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;"
            "border: None;")
        self.dk_2.setObjectName("dk_2")



        self.dk_edit_2 = QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.dk_edit_2.setGeometry(QRect(200, 90, 151, 26))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.dk_edit_2.setFont(font)
        self.dk_edit_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;"
            "border-radius: 10;"
            "color: white;"
            "padding-left: 7px;"
            "padding-right: 7px;")
        self.dk_edit_2.setObjectName("dk_edit_2")



        self.fio_edit_set_2 = QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.fio_edit_set_2.setGeometry(QRect(100, 50, 261, 26))
        self.fio_edit_set_2.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.fio_edit_set_2.setFont(font)
        self.fio_edit_set_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;"
            "border-radius: 10;"
            "color: white;"
            "padding-left: 7px;"
            "padding-right: 7px;")
        self.fio_edit_set_2.setObjectName("fio_edit_set_2")



        self.fio_set_2 = QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.fio_set_2.setGeometry(QRect(40, 53, 51, 16))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.fio_set_2.setFont(font)
        self.fio_set_2.setText("ФИО:")
        self.fio_set_2.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;"
            "border: None;")
        self.fio_set_2.setObjectName("fio_set_2")

        self.deleten_2 = QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.deleten_2.setGeometry(QRect(378, 10, 24, 24))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.deleten_2.setFont(font)
        self.deleten_2.setText("X")
        self.deleten_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.deleten_2.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton {"
            "    background-color: None;"
            "    border: 2px solid white;"
            "    border-radius: 7;"
            "    color: white;"
            "}"
            ""
            "QPushButton:hover {"
            "    background-color: #FF381E;"
            "    border-color: #FF381E;"
            "    color: white;"
            "}"
            ""
            "")
        self.deleten_2.setObjectName("deleten_2")

   
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox_2)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainwindow = MainWindow()
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
widget.setFixedWidth(686)
widget.setFixedHeight(580)
widget.setWindowTitle('Forwork')
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="enabled">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>686</width>
    <height>580</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: #EB5F42;

</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="Rashitat">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>280</x>
     <y>475</y>
     <width>161</width>
     <height>41</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <family>Yu Gothic UI</family>
     <pointsize>11</pointsize>
     <weight>75</weight>
     <italic>false</italic>
     <bold>true</bold>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="cursor">
    <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0.00568182 rgba(252,166,51,255), stop:1 rgba(250,148,86, 255));
    border-radius: 10;
    color: white;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0.00568182 rgba(252,176,82,255), stop:1 rgba(250,155,96, 255));
}



QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0.00568182 rgba(252,166,51,255), stop:1 rgba(250,148,86, 255));
}



</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Рассчитать</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QComboBox" name="vibor">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>540</x>
     <y>35</y>
     <width>111</width>
     <height>24</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">color: #EB5F42;
background-color: #FDD2BF;
border-radius: 8;
padding-left: 7px;</string>
   </property>
   <property name="editable">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
   <item>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Солошенко М.М.</string>
    </property>
   </item>
   <item>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Солошенко Н.В.</string>
    </property>
   </item>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="fio">
   <property name="enabled">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>245</x>
     <y>80</y>
     <width>221</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>10</pointsize>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="toolTip">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;
border-radius: 12;
color: white;
padding-left: 7px;
padding-right: 7px;</string>
   </property>
   <property name="alignment">
    <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="Otv">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>225</x>
     <y>385</y>
     <width>271</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <family>Myanmar Text</family>
     <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     <weight>75</weight>
     <bold>true</bold>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">color: white;</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Ответ : </string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="image">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>295</x>
     <y>200</y>
     <width>111</width>
     <height>121</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="pixmap">
    <pixmap>Images/4829873-128.png</pixmap>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>25</x>
     <y>120</y>
     <width>45</width>
     <height>311</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color:  #F07955;

border-radius: 14;</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="settings_hm">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>-1</x>
      <y>135</y>
      <width>47</width>
      <height>47</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="cursor">
     <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    border-radius: 0;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: #F09073;
}
</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="icon">
     <iconset>
      <normaloff>Images/2849830-32.png</normaloff>Images/2849830-32.png</iconset>
    </property>
    <property name="iconSize">
     <size>
      <width>32</width>
      <height>32</height>
     </size>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="home_hm">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>-1</x>
      <y>90</y>
      <width>47</width>
      <height>47</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="cursor">
     <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    border-radius: 0;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: #F09073;
}

</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="icon">
     <iconset>
      <normaloff>Images/3643769-32.png</normaloff>Images/3643769-32.png</iconset>
    </property>
    <property name="iconSize">
     <size>
      <width>32</width>
      <height>32</height>
     </size>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QFrame" name="podch">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>-1</x>
      <y>90</y>
      <width>4</width>
      <height>47</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: #E8F6EF;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="nash_dat_otd">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>265</x>
     <y>135</y>
     <width>181</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <pointsize>10</pointsize>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;
border-radius: 12;
color: white;
padding-left: 7px;
padding-right: 7px;</string>
   </property>
   <property name="alignment">
    <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**settings.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="enabled">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>686</width>
    <height>580</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: #EB5F42;</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="dock" native="true">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>25</x>
     <y>120</y>
     <width>45</width>
     <height>311</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="autoFillBackground">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color:  #F07955;

border-radius: 14;</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="settings_set">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>-1</x>
      <y>135</y>
      <width>47</width>
      <height>47</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="cursor">
     <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    border-radius: 0;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: #F09073;
}
</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="icon">
     <iconset>
      <normaloff>Images/2849830-32.png</normaloff>Images/2849830-32.png</iconset>
    </property>
    <property name="iconSize">
     <size>
      <width>32</width>
      <height>32</height>
     </size>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="home_set">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>-1</x>
      <y>90</y>
      <width>47</width>
      <height>47</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="cursor">
     <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    border-radius: 0;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: #F09073;
}

</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="icon">
     <iconset>
      <normaloff>Images/3643769-32.png</normaloff>Images/3643769-32.png</iconset>
    </property>
    <property name="iconSize">
     <size>
      <width>32</width>
      <height>32</height>
     </size>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QFrame" name="podch_set">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>-1</x>
      <y>137</y>
      <width>4</width>
      <height>45</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: #E8F6EF;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>140</x>
     <y>50</y>
     <width>531</width>
     <height>511</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">border: None;</string>
   </property>
   <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="widgetResizable">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>531</width>
      <height>511</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
     <item>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
       <property name="spacing">
        <number>25</number>
       </property>
       <property name="leftMargin">
        <number>10</number>
       </property>
       <property name="topMargin">
        <number>10</number>
       </property>
       <property name="bottomMargin">
        <number>50</number>
       </property>
       <item>
        <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>411</width>
           <height>251</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>411</width>
           <height>251</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;
border-radius: 10;</string>
         </property>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="save_people">
          <property name="geometry">
           <rect>
            <x>290</x>
            <y>200</y>
            <width>86</width>
            <height>31</height>
           </rect>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <pointsize>10</pointsize>
           </font>
          </property>
          <property name="cursor">
           <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
          </property>
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">border: 2px solid #50DD6E;
color: white;
border-radius: 7;</string>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>Save</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
         <widget class="QLabel" name="pdk">
          <property name="geometry">
           <rect>
            <x>40</x>
            <y>130</y>
            <width>161</width>
            <height>21</height>
           </rect>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <family>MS Reference Sans Serif</family>
            <pointsize>13</pointsize>
            <weight>50</weight>
            <bold>false</bold>
           </font>
          </property>
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">color: white;
border: None;</string>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>Посл. дата отд.: </string>
          </property>
         </widget>
         <widget class="QLineEdit" name="dk_edit">
          <property name="geometry">
           <rect>
            <x>200</x>
            <y>90</y>
            <width>151</width>
            <height>26</height>
           </rect>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <pointsize>10</pointsize>
           </font>
          </property>
          <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
           <enum>Qt::PreventContextMenu</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;
border-radius: 10;
color: white;
padding-left: 7px;
padding-right: 7px;</string>
          </property>
          <property name="alignment">
           <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
          </property>
         </widget>
         <widget class="QLabel" name="dk">
          <property name="geometry">
           <rect>
            <x>40</x>
            <y>90</y>
            <width>141</width>
            <height>21</height>
           </rect>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <family>MS Reference Sans Serif</family>
            <pointsize>13</pointsize>
            <weight>50</weight>
            <bold>false</bold>
           </font>
          </property>
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">color: white;
border: None;</string>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>Дата контракта: </string>
          </property>
         </widget>
         <widget class="QLabel" name="fio_set">
          <property name="geometry">
           <rect>
            <x>40</x>
            <y>53</y>
            <width>51</width>
            <height>16</height>
           </rect>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <family>MS Reference Sans Serif</family>
            <pointsize>13</pointsize>
            <weight>50</weight>
            <bold>false</bold>
           </font>
          </property>
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">color: white;
border: None;</string>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>ФИО:</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
         <widget class="QLineEdit" name="pdk_edit">
          <property name="geometry">
           <rect>
            <x>200</x>
            <y>130</y>
            <width>171</width>
            <height>26</height>
           </rect>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <pointsize>10</pointsize>
           </font>
          </property>
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;
border-radius: 10;
color: white;
padding-left: 7px;
padding-right: 7px;</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="edit">
          <property name="enabled">
           <bool>false</bool>
          </property>
          <property name="geometry">
           <rect>
            <x>190</x>
            <y>200</y>
            <width>86</width>
            <height>31</height>
           </rect>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <pointsize>10</pointsize>
           </font>
          </property>
          <property name="cursor">
           <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
          </property>
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">border: 2px solid #4E9CFD;
color: white;
border-radius: 7;</string>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>Edit</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="deleten">
          <property name="enabled">
           <bool>true</bool>
          </property>
          <property name="geometry">
           <rect>
            <x>378</x>
            <y>10</y>
            <width>24</width>
            <height>24</height>
           </rect>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <pointsize>10</pointsize>
           </font>
          </property>
          <property name="cursor">
           <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
          </property>
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background-color: None;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 7;
    color: white;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: #FF381E;
    border-color: #FF381E;
    color: white;
}



</string>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>X</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
         <widget class="QLabel" name="uzn">
          <property name="geometry">
           <rect>
            <x>35</x>
            <y>203</y>
            <width>27</width>
            <height>27</height>
           </rect>
          </property>
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;</string>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string/>
          </property>
          <property name="pixmap">
           <pixmap>Images/383085-32.png</pixmap>
          </property>
          <property name="alignment">
           <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
          </property>
         </widget>
         <widget class="Line" name="sep">
          <property name="geometry">
           <rect>
            <x>30</x>
            <y>180</y>
            <width>351</width>
            <height>2</height>
           </rect>
          </property>
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">background-color: #FDD2BF;
border: 1px solid #FDD2BF;</string>
          </property>
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
          </property>
         </widget>
         <widget class="QLineEdit" name="fio_edit_set">
          <property name="geometry">
           <rect>
            <x>100</x>
            <y>50</y>
            <width>261</width>
            <height>26</height>
           </rect>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <pointsize>10</pointsize>
           </font>
          </property>
          <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
           <enum>Qt::PreventContextMenu</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;
border-radius: 10;
color: white;
padding-left: 7px;
padding-right: 7px;</string>
          </property>
          <property name="alignment">
           <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
          </property>
          <property name="clearButtonEnabled">
           <bool>true</bool>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>150</x>
     <y>30</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>PushButton</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас очень тяжелый код. На **`SO`** много постов о том как правильно использовать `QStackedWidget` - рекомендую найти и проработать.

Основная идея в том, что однажды созданная страница
добавляется в `QStackedWidget` и далее вы только устанавливаете индекс страницы,
которую надо показать.

```
widget = QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(mainwindow)               # страница с индексои 0 
...
widget.addWidget(self.settings)            # страница с индексои 1
```

вы же постоянно пересоздаете новые страницы и это не правильно.
Дополнительно читаем https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html

Вторая проблема в понимании построения и использовании
динамических виджетов (`groupBox_2`). Я по-моему уже вам писал.
Не надо их делать атрибутами класса, это только путает вас и
вы думаете если сделать `self.groupBox_2`, вы сможете получить
доступ к виджету из какого-нибудь другого метода. **`Нет, не получится`**.
Вам надо где-то сохранять эти вновь созданные `groupBox_2` -
для этого я создал словарь, в котором объекты `groupBox_2`
будут как значения, а ключом будет имя этого объекта (`object_name`).
Заметьте что имя этого объекта - уникально,
вот как я его строю:

```
class Settings_l(QDialog, Settings_Ui):
    ...
        self.object_name = f'groupBox_{self.parent.setting_num}'
    ...
    def new(self):
        ...
        groupBox_2.setObjectName(self.object_name)  
        ...
        self.parent.settings_dict[self.object_name] = groupBox_2
        self.parent.setting_num += 1
        self.object_name = f'groupBox_{self.parent.setting_num}'
     ...

class MainWindow(QDialog, Main_Ui):
    ...
        self.setting_num = 0
    ...
```

---

Обратите внимание, что после создания нового объекта `groupBox_2`
мы сохраняем его в **`словарь`**:

```
    self.parent.settings_dict[self.object_name] = groupBox_2
```

а в привязке сигналов-слотов объектов кнопок мы передаем `self.object_name`
дополнительным параметром:

```
    self.edit_2.clicked.connect(
        lambda ch, obj=self.object_name: self.click_btn_edit(obj))
```

и благодаря этому в слоте `click_btn_edit()` мы можем получить доступ
к любому дочернему элементу  объекта `groupBox_2`.

---

При удалении желаемого объекта `groupBox_2`
надо удалить его и как виджет и удалить соответствующую запись
в словаре  `settings_dict`:

```
def delete_groupBox(self, obj):
    msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(None, 
        "Внимание подтвердите удаление объекта!", 
        f"Вы действительно хотите удалить '{obj}' ?",  
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel)
    if msgBox == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel:
        return
        
    _obj = self.parent.settings_dict[obj]
    _obj.deleteLater()
    self.parent.settings_dict.pop(obj)
```

---

А также смотрите некоторые комментарии по тексту кода.

**PS** Старайтесь давать правильные имена переменным, функциям/методам -
почитайте [PEP 8](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html)

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
#from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

# ! pyuic5 main.ui -o q1314146_main_ui.py -x
from q1314146_main_ui import Ui_Dialog as Main_Ui

# ! pyuic5 settings.ui -o q1314146_settings_ui.py -x

# !!! ВНИМАНИЕ - после конвертации из модуля q1314146_settings_ui.py 
# !!! было убрано ненужное наполнение.
from q1314146_settings_ui import Ui_Dialog as Settings_Ui

'''
# ! вы не предоставили модуль delete.ui
# ! я реализовал это в методе delete_groupBox
class Delete(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Delete, self).__init__()

        print(f'class Delete(QDialog): {self} ?????????') #
        
        loadUi("delete.ui", self)
        
        self.podtvergdenie.clicked.connect(self.podtvergdenies)
        self.otmena.clicked.connect(self.otmens)

    def podtvergdenies(self):
        pass

    def otmens(self):
        self.close()    
'''

class Settings_l(QDialog, Settings_Ui):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                             # +++ parent
        super(Settings_l, self).__init__()
        
##        loadUi("q1314146_settings.ui", self)
        self.setupUi(self)                                       # +++
        
        self.parent = parent                                     # +++ parent
        self.object_name = f'groupBox_{self.parent.setting_num}' # +++
        
        self.home_set.clicked.connect(self.go_home)
# ?      self.deleten.clicked.connect(self.delete)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.new)

    def go_home(self):
        widget.setCurrentIndex(0)                                # +++ 0
        ''' 
# так делать неправильно        
        mainwindow = MainWindow()
        widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex() + 1)
        '''

        '''
    def delete(self):
        self.delete_rab = Delete()
        self.delete_rab.resize(280, 175)
        self.delete_rab.setFixedWidth(280)
        self.delete_rab.setFixedHeight(175)
        self.delete_rab.setWindowTitle('Удаление')
        self.delete_rab.show()
        '''

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def new(self):
        print(f'def new(self):', self.parent.setting_num) #
# ?        self.groupBox_2 = QGroupBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        groupBox_2 = QGroupBox(self.object_name, self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        groupBox_2.setFixedSize(QSize(411, 251))
        groupBox_2.setStyleSheet(u"border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;\n"  
            "border-radius: 10;"
            "background-color: #BB371A;"
        )
        groupBox_2.setObjectName(self.object_name)

#  -->  vvvv <---- вот эти self также не нужны при динамических созданиях
        self.save_people_2 = QPushButton("Save", groupBox_2)
        self.save_people_2.setGeometry(QRect(290, 200, 86, 31))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.save_people_2.setFont(font)
        self.save_people_2.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.save_people_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #50DD6E;"
            "color: white;"
            "border-radius: 7;")
        self.save_people_2.setObjectName("save_people_2")

        self.edit_2 = QPushButton("Edit", groupBox_2)
        self.edit_2.setGeometry(QRect(190, 200, 86, 31))
        self.edit_2.setFont(font)
        self.edit_2.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.edit_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #4E9CFD;"
            "color: white;\n"
            "border-radius: 7;")
        self.edit_2.setObjectName("edit_2")
        self.edit_2.clicked.connect(                                   # !!!
            lambda ch, obj=self.object_name: self.click_btn_edit(obj)) # !!!

        self.uzn_2 = QLabel(groupBox_2)
        self.uzn_2.setGeometry(QRect(35, 203, 27, 27))
        self.uzn_2.setText(None)
#        self.uzn_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Images/383085-32.png"))
        self.uzn_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("ball.png"))
        self.uzn_2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.uzn_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;")
        self.uzn_2.setObjectName("uzn_2")

        self.sep_2 = QFrame(groupBox_2)
        self.sep_2.setGeometry(QRect(30, 180, 351, 2))
        self.sep_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.sep_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.sep_2.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: #00f;"
            "border: 1px solid #FDD2BF;")
        self.sep_2.setObjectName("sep_2")

        self.pdk_2 = QLabel(groupBox_2)
        self.pdk_2.setGeometry(QRect(40, 130, 161, 21))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pdk_2.setFont(font)
        self.pdk_2.setText("Посл. дата отд.: ")
        self.pdk_2.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;"
            "border: None;")
        self.pdk_2.setObjectName("pdk_2")

        self.pdk_edit_2 = QLineEdit(groupBox_2)
        self.pdk_edit_2.setGeometry(QRect(200, 130, 171, 26))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pdk_edit_2.setFont(font)
        self.pdk_edit_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;"
            "border-radius: 10;"
            "color: white;"
            "padding-left: 7px;"
            "padding-right: 7px;")
        self.pdk_edit_2.setObjectName("pdk_edit_2")

        self.dk_2 = QLabel(groupBox_2)
        self.dk_2.setGeometry(QRect(40, 90, 161, 21))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.dk_2.setFont(font)
        self.dk_2.setText("Дата контракта: ")
        self.dk_2.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;"
            "border: None;")
        self.dk_2.setObjectName("dk_2")

        self.dk_edit_2 = QLineEdit(groupBox_2)
        self.dk_edit_2.setGeometry(QRect(200, 90, 151, 26))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.dk_edit_2.setFont(font)
        self.dk_edit_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;"
            "border-radius: 10;"
            "color: white;"
            "padding-left: 7px;"
            "padding-right: 7px;")
        self.dk_edit_2.setObjectName("dk_edit_2")

        self.fio_edit_set_2 = QLineEdit(groupBox_2)
        self.fio_edit_set_2.setGeometry(QRect(100, 50, 261, 26))
        self.fio_edit_set_2.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.fio_edit_set_2.setFont(font)
        self.fio_edit_set_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;"
            "border-radius: 10;"
            "color: white;"
            "padding-left: 7px;"
            "padding-right: 7px;")
        self.fio_edit_set_2.setObjectName("fio_edit_set_2")

        self.fio_set_2 = QLabel(groupBox_2)
        self.fio_set_2.setGeometry(QRect(40, 53, 51, 16))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.fio_set_2.setFont(font)
        self.fio_set_2.setText("ФИО:")
        self.fio_set_2.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;"
            "border: None;")
        self.fio_set_2.setObjectName("fio_set_2")

        self.deleten_2 = QPushButton(groupBox_2)
        self.deleten_2.setGeometry(QRect(378, 10, 24, 24))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.deleten_2.setFont(font)
        self.deleten_2.setText("X")
        self.deleten_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.deleten_2.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton {"
            "    background-color: None;"
            "    border: 2px solid white;"
            "    border-radius: 7;"
            "    color: white;"
            "}"
            ""
            "QPushButton:hover {"
            "    background-color: #FF381E;"
            "    border-color: #FF381E;"
            "    color: white;"
            "}"
            ""
            "")
        self.deleten_2.setObjectName("deleten_2")

        self.deleten_2.clicked.connect(                                 # !!!
            lambda ch, obj=self.object_name: self.delete_groupBox(obj)) # !!!
            
        self.parent.settings_dict[self.object_name] = groupBox_2
        self.parent.setting_num += 1
        self.object_name = f'groupBox_{self.parent.setting_num}'

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(groupBox_2)

    def click_btn_edit(self, obj):                                      # !!!
        btns = self.parent.settings_dict[obj].findChildren(QPushButton)
        lins = self.parent.settings_dict[obj].findChildren(QLineEdit)
        print(f'\nВы собираетесь редактировать: {obj}') #
        print(f'\n{obj} имеет PushButtons:') #
        print(* [[btn.text(), btn.objectName()]  for btn in btns], sep='\n')
        print(f'\n{obj} имеет LineEdits:') #
        print(* [[lin.text(), lin.objectName()]  for lin in lins], sep='\n')

        _obj = self.parent.settings_dict[obj]                            # !!!
        print(f'{_obj.findChild(QLineEdit, "fio_edit_set_2").text()}')                 

    def delete_groupBox(self, obj):                                      # !!!
        msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(None, 
            "Внимание подтвердите удаление объекта!", 
            f"Вы действительно хотите удалить '{obj}' ?",  
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel)

        if msgBox == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel:
            return
            
        _obj = self.parent.settings_dict[obj]
        _obj.deleteLater()                                            # !!!
        self.parent.settings_dict.pop(obj)                            # !!!
        

class MainWindow(QDialog, Main_Ui):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

#        loadUi("q1314146_main.ui", self)
        self.setupUi(self)                                            # !!!
        
        self.setting_num = 0                                          # !!!
        self.settings_dict = {}                                       # !!!
                
        self.settings_hm.clicked.connect(self.go_setting)

# !!!       # v^
        self.settings = Settings_l(self)
# ?        widget.addWidget(self.settings)            # self.  1      
# ?        widget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10, self.add_settings)               # !!!

    def add_settings(self):
        widget.addWidget(self.settings)            # self.  1  

    def go_setting(self):
        widget.setCurrentIndex(1)                                      # !!! 1
        
        
        ''' 
# так делать неправильно 
    def setting(self):
        settings = Settings_l()
        widget.addWidget(settings)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex() + 1)
        '''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    widget = QStackedWidget()
    widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
    
#    widget.setFixedWidth(686)
#    widget.setFixedHeight(580)
    widget.resize(686, 580)

    widget.setWindowTitle('Forwork')
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1314146_main_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.setEnabled(True)
        Dialog.resize(686, 580)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: #EB5F42;")
        self.Rashitat = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.Rashitat.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 475, 161, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic UI")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Rashitat.setFont(font)
        self.Rashitat.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.Rashitat.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0.00568182 rgba(252,166,51,255), stop:1 rgba(250,148,86, 255));\n"
"    border-radius: 10;\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0.00568182 rgba(252,176,82,255), stop:1 rgba(250,155,96, 255));\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0.00568182 rgba(252,166,51,255), stop:1 rgba(250,148,86, 255));\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.Rashitat.setObjectName("Rashitat")
        self.vibor = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.vibor.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 35, 111, 24))
        self.vibor.setStyleSheet("color: #EB5F42;\n"
"background-color: #FDD2BF;\n"
"border-radius: 8;\n"
"padding-left: 7px;")
        self.vibor.setEditable(False)
        self.vibor.setObjectName("vibor")
        self.vibor.addItem("")
        self.vibor.addItem("")
        self.fio = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.fio.setEnabled(False)
        self.fio.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(245, 80, 221, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.fio.setFont(font)
        self.fio.setToolTip("")
        self.fio.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;\n"
"border-radius: 12;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"padding-left: 7px;\n"
"padding-right: 7px;")
        self.fio.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.fio.setObjectName("fio")
        self.Otv = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.Otv.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(225, 385, 271, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Myanmar Text")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Otv.setFont(font)
        self.Otv.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
        self.Otv.setObjectName("Otv")
        self.image = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.image.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(295, 200, 111, 121))
        self.image.setText("")
        self.image.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("ball.png"))
        self.image.setObjectName("image")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 120, 45, 311))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:  #F07955;\n"
"\n"
"border-radius: 14;")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.settings_hm = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.settings_hm.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, 135, 47, 47))
        self.settings_hm.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.settings_hm.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border-radius: 0;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: #F09073;\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.settings_hm.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.settings_hm.setIcon(icon)
        self.settings_hm.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
        self.settings_hm.setObjectName("settings_hm")
        self.home_hm = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.home_hm.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, 90, 47, 47))
        self.home_hm.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.home_hm.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border-radius: 0;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: #F09073;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.home_hm.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("im.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.home_hm.setIcon(icon1)
        self.home_hm.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
        self.home_hm.setObjectName("home_hm")
        self.podch = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widget)
        self.podch.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, 90, 4, 47))
        self.podch.setStyleSheet("background-color: #E8F6EF;")
        self.podch.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.podch.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.podch.setObjectName("podch")
        self.nash_dat_otd = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.nash_dat_otd.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(265, 135, 181, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.nash_dat_otd.setFont(font)
        self.nash_dat_otd.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;\n"
"border-radius: 12;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"padding-left: 7px;\n"
"padding-right: 7px;")
        self.nash_dat_otd.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.nash_dat_otd.setObjectName("nash_dat_otd")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.Rashitat.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Рассчитать"))
        self.vibor.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Солошенко М.М."))
        self.vibor.setItemText(1, _translate("Dialog", "Солошенко Н.В."))
        self.Otv.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ответ : "))
```

---

ДЛЯ МОДУЛЯ
**q1314146_settings_ui.py** НЕ ХВАТИЛО МЕСТО, ПУБЛИКУЮ В СЛЕДУЮЩЕМ ОТВЕТЕ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Comment: @ITProgram пожалуйста. Удачи вам.

Answer (score 2):

**ПРОДОЛЖЕНИЕ ОТВЕТА.**

---

**q1314146_settings_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.setEnabled(True)
        Dialog.resize(686, 580)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: #EB5F42;")
        self.dock = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.dock.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 120, 45, 311))
        self.dock.setAutoFillBackground(False)
#
        self.dock.setStyleSheet("background-color:  #007955; border-radius: 14;")
        self.dock.setObjectName("dock")
        self.settings_set = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.dock)
        self.settings_set.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, 135, 47, 47))
        self.settings_set.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.settings_set.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border-radius: 0;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: #F09073;\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.settings_set.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.settings_set.setIcon(icon)
        self.settings_set.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
        self.settings_set.setObjectName("settings_set")
#        
        self.home_set = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.dock)
        self.home_set.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, 90, 47, 47))
        self.home_set.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.home_set.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border-radius: 0;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: #F09073;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.home_set.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("im.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.home_set.setIcon(icon1)
        self.home_set.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
        self.home_set.setObjectName("home_set")
        self.podch_set = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.dock)
        self.podch_set.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, 137, 4, 45))
        self.podch_set.setStyleSheet("background-color: #E8F6EF;")
        self.podch_set.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.podch_set.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.podch_set.setObjectName("podch_set")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(Dialog)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 50, 531, 511))
        self.scrollArea.setStyleSheet("border: None;")
        
#        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 531, 511))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
# +        
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setStyleSheet("background-color: #B3E283;")
        
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, -1, 50)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(25)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
# !!! ВНИМАНИЕ - то что закомментировано сдесь быть не должно.        
        '''
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.groupBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(411, 251))
        self.groupBox.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(411, 251))
        self.groupBox.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;\n"
"border-radius: 10;")
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.save_people = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.save_people.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 200, 86, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.save_people.setFont(font)
        self.save_people.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.save_people.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #50DD6E;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 7;")
        self.save_people.setObjectName("save_people")
        self.pdk = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.pdk.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 130, 161, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pdk.setFont(font)
        self.pdk.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
"border: None;")
        self.pdk.setObjectName("pdk")
        self.dk_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.dk_edit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 90, 151, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.dk_edit.setFont(font)
        self.dk_edit.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.PreventContextMenu)
        self.dk_edit.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;\n"
"border-radius: 10;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"padding-left: 7px;\n"
"padding-right: 7px;")
        self.dk_edit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.dk_edit.setObjectName("dk_edit")
        self.dk = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.dk.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 90, 141, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.dk.setFont(font)
        self.dk.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
"border: None;")
        self.dk.setObjectName("dk")
        self.fio_set = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.fio_set.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 53, 51, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.fio_set.setFont(font)
        self.fio_set.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
"border: None;")
        self.fio_set.setObjectName("fio_set")
        self.pdk_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.pdk_edit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 130, 171, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pdk_edit.setFont(font)
        self.pdk_edit.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;\n"
"border-radius: 10;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"padding-left: 7px;\n"
"padding-right: 7px;")
        self.pdk_edit.setObjectName("pdk_edit")
        self.edit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.edit.setEnabled(False)
        self.edit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 200, 86, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.edit.setFont(font)
        self.edit.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.edit.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #4E9CFD;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"border-radius: 7;")
        self.edit.setObjectName("edit")
        self.deleten = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.deleten.setEnabled(True)
        self.deleten.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(378, 10, 24, 24))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.deleten.setFont(font)
        self.deleten.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.deleten.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: None;\n"
"    border: 2px solid white;\n"
"    border-radius: 7;\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: #FF381E;\n"
"    border-color: #FF381E;\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.deleten.setObjectName("deleten")
        self.uzn = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.uzn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(35, 203, 27, 27))
        self.uzn.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;")
        self.uzn.setText("")
        self.uzn.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("ball.png"))
        self.uzn.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.uzn.setObjectName("uzn")
        self.sep = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.groupBox)
        self.sep.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 180, 351, 2))
        self.sep.setStyleSheet("background-color: #FDD2BF;\n"
"border: 1px solid #FDD2BF;")
        self.sep.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.sep.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.sep.setObjectName("sep")
        self.fio_edit_set = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.fio_edit_set.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 50, 261, 26))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.fio_edit_set.setFont(font)
        self.fio_edit_set.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.PreventContextMenu)
        self.fio_edit_set.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;\n"
"border-radius: 10;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"padding-left: 7px;\n"
"padding-right: 7px;")
        self.fio_edit_set.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.fio_edit_set.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.fio_edit_set.setObjectName("fio_edit_set")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        '''
        
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 30, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: #BB371A;")  # +++
        
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        '''
        self.save_people.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Save"))
        self.pdk.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Посл. дата отд.: "))
        self.dk.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Дата контракта: "))
        self.fio_set.setText(_translate("Dialog", "ФИО:"))
        self.edit.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Edit"))
        self.deleten.setText(_translate("Dialog", "X"))
        '''
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Add New")) # !!! Add New
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мои глаза немного офигели от расцветок :D

Comment: @gil9red код тяжелый в понимании, вот и раскрасил как попало, чтобы понять где и что :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо