# Как выбрать нужное значение QLineEdit?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, сигналы-слоты

Я хочу в переменную `otv_fio` поместить значение `lineEdit`.

Но так как у меня создаётся много `lineEdit` то, прописал  `setObjectName`, который увеличивается.

```py
class MainWindow(QDialog, Main_Ui):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)                                            
        
        self.setting_num = 0
        ...

class Settings_l(QDialog, Settings_Ui):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):                            
        super(Settings_l, self).__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.parent = parent  
                                   
        self.object_name = f'groupBox_{self.parent.setting_num}'

        self.fio_edit_set_2_obj = f'fio_edit_set_{self.parent.setting_num}'

        self.add_new_gb.clicked.connect(self.new)


    def new(self):

        groupBox_2 = QGroupBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        groupBox_2.setFixedSize(QSize(411, 251))
        groupBox_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;"  
            "border-radius: 10;"
            "background-color: None;"
        )
        groupBox_2.setObjectName(self.object_name)


        save_people_2 = QPushButton("Save", groupBox_2)
        save_people_2.setGeometry(QRect(290, 200, 86, 31))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        save_people_2.setFont(font)
        save_people_2.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        save_people_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #50DD6E;"
            "color: white;"
            "border-radius: 7;")

        save_people_2.clicked.connect(                                   
            lambda ch, obj_2 = self.object_name: self.click_btn_save(obj_2))

        ...
        
        fio_edit_set_2 = QLineEdit(groupBox_2)
        fio_edit_set_2.setGeometry(QRect(100, 50, 261, 26))
        fio_edit_set_2.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        fio_edit_set_2.setFont(font)
        fio_edit_set_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;"
            "border-radius: 10;"
            "color: white;"
            "padding-left: 7px;"
            "padding-right: 7px;"
            "background-color: #EB5F42;")

        fio_edit_set_2.setObjectName(self.fio_edit_set_2_obj)

        self.parent.settings_dict[self.object_name] = groupBox_2
        self.parent.setting_num += 1
        self.object_name = f'groupBox_{self.parent.setting_num}'

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(groupBox_2)


    def click_btn_save(self, obj_2):

        num_obj = obj_2[9:]

        otv_f = f'fio_edit_set_{num_obj}'
        # в этой переменной я пытаюсь узнать занчение которое находится в lineEdit
        otv_fio = otv_f.text()
```

---

Ошибка:

> AttributeError -  'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Как исправить?

Comment: Если у вас список виджетов, то работайте с списком, не нужно извращаться с генерацией имен переменных. У вас явная проблема XY. Предоставьте минимальный пример и описание что хотите сделать :)

Comment: А зачем ты делаешь .text()? В чем кармический смысл вызова этого метода? Чем не устраивает просто print(otv_f)?

Comment: Исправить очень просто - нужно не пытаться применить к строке (цитата: "в которой храниться название", название это текст, текст это строка) метод, который у строк отсутствует.

Comment: ITProgram пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] и просто расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне казалось, что в одном из предыдущих ответов
[Вопросы с программой PyQt5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1314146/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-pyqt5)
я вам все рассказал.
Повторение — мать учения.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from q1314146_main_ui import Ui_Dialog as Main_Ui
from q1314146_settings_ui import Ui_Dialog as Settings_Ui


class Settings_l(QDialog, Settings_Ui):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):             
        super(Settings_l, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.parent = parent                     
        self.object_name = f'groupBox_{self.parent.setting_num}' 
        
        self.home_set.clicked.connect(self.go_home)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.new)

    def go_home(self):
        widget.setCurrentIndex(0)      

    def new(self):
        print(f'def new(self):', self.parent.setting_num) #
        groupBox_2 = QGroupBox(self.object_name, self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        groupBox_2.setFixedSize(QSize(411, 251))
        groupBox_2.setStyleSheet(u"border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;\n"  
            "border-radius: 10;"
            "background-color: #BB371A;"
        )
        groupBox_2.setObjectName(self.object_name)

        save_people_2 = QPushButton("Save", groupBox_2)
        save_people_2.setGeometry(QRect(290, 200, 86, 31))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        save_people_2.setFont(font)
        save_people_2.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        save_people_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #50DD6E;"
            "color: white;"
            "border-radius: 7;")
        save_people_2.setObjectName("save_people_2")
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        save_people_2.clicked.connect(                                   
            lambda ch, obj=self.object_name: self.click_btn_save(obj)) # !!!        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

#       vvvv <---- вот эти self также не нужны 
        self.edit_2 = QPushButton("Edit", groupBox_2)
        self.edit_2.setGeometry(QRect(190, 200, 86, 31))
        self.edit_2.setFont(font)
        self.edit_2.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.edit_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #4E9CFD;"
            "color: white;\n"
            "border-radius: 7;")
        self.edit_2.setObjectName("edit_2")
        self.edit_2.clicked.connect(                                  
            lambda ch, obj=self.object_name: self.click_btn_edit(obj))

        self.uzn_2 = QLabel(groupBox_2)
        self.uzn_2.setGeometry(QRect(35, 203, 27, 27))
        self.uzn_2.setText(None)
#        self.uzn_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Images/383085-32.png"))
        self.uzn_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("ball.png"))
        self.uzn_2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.uzn_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;")
        self.uzn_2.setObjectName("uzn_2")

        self.sep_2 = QFrame(groupBox_2)
        self.sep_2.setGeometry(QRect(30, 180, 351, 2))
        self.sep_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.sep_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.sep_2.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: #00f;"
            "border: 1px solid #FDD2BF;")
        self.sep_2.setObjectName("sep_2")

        self.pdk_2 = QLabel(groupBox_2)
        self.pdk_2.setGeometry(QRect(40, 130, 161, 21))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pdk_2.setFont(font)
        self.pdk_2.setText("Посл. дата отд.: ")
        self.pdk_2.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;"
            "border: None;")
        self.pdk_2.setObjectName("pdk_2")

        self.pdk_edit_2 = QLineEdit(groupBox_2)
        self.pdk_edit_2.setGeometry(QRect(200, 130, 171, 26))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pdk_edit_2.setFont(font)
        self.pdk_edit_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;"
            "border-radius: 10;"
            "color: white;"
            "padding-left: 7px;"
            "padding-right: 7px;")
        self.pdk_edit_2.setObjectName("pdk_edit_2")

        self.dk_2 = QLabel(groupBox_2)
        self.dk_2.setGeometry(QRect(40, 90, 161, 21))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.dk_2.setFont(font)
        self.dk_2.setText("Дата контракта: ")
        self.dk_2.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;"
            "border: None;")
        self.dk_2.setObjectName("dk_2")

        self.dk_edit_2 = QLineEdit(groupBox_2)
        self.dk_edit_2.setGeometry(QRect(200, 90, 151, 26))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.dk_edit_2.setFont(font)
        self.dk_edit_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;"
            "border-radius: 10;"
            "color: white;"
            "padding-left: 7px;"
            "padding-right: 7px;")
        self.dk_edit_2.setObjectName("dk_edit_2")

        self.fio_edit_set_2 = QLineEdit(groupBox_2)
        self.fio_edit_set_2.setGeometry(QRect(100, 50, 261, 26))
        self.fio_edit_set_2.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.fio_edit_set_2.setFont(font)
        self.fio_edit_set_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;"
            "border-radius: 10;"
            "color: white;"
            "padding-left: 7px;"
            "padding-right: 7px;")
        self.fio_edit_set_2.setObjectName("fio_edit_set_2")

        self.fio_set_2 = QLabel(groupBox_2)
        self.fio_set_2.setGeometry(QRect(40, 53, 51, 16))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Reference Sans Serif")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.fio_set_2.setFont(font)
        self.fio_set_2.setText("ФИО:")
        self.fio_set_2.setStyleSheet(
            "color: white;"
            "border: None;")
        self.fio_set_2.setObjectName("fio_set_2")

        self.deleten_2 = QPushButton(groupBox_2)
        self.deleten_2.setGeometry(QRect(378, 10, 24, 24))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.deleten_2.setFont(font)
        self.deleten_2.setText("X")
        self.deleten_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.deleten_2.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton {"
            "    background-color: None;"
            "    border: 2px solid white;"
            "    border-radius: 7;"
            "    color: white;"
            "}"
            ""
            "QPushButton:hover {"
            "    background-color: #FF381E;"
            "    border-color: #FF381E;"
            "    color: white;"
            "}"
            ""
            "")
        self.deleten_2.setObjectName("deleten_2")

        self.deleten_2.clicked.connect(                                 # !!!
            lambda ch, obj=self.object_name: self.delete_groupBox(obj)) # !!!
            
        self.parent.settings_dict[self.object_name] = groupBox_2
        self.parent.setting_num += 1
        self.object_name = f'groupBox_{self.parent.setting_num}'

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(groupBox_2)

    def click_btn_edit(self, obj):                                      # !!!
        btns = self.parent.settings_dict[obj].findChildren(QPushButton)
        lins = self.parent.settings_dict[obj].findChildren(QLineEdit)
        print(f'\nВы собираетесь редактировать: {obj}') #
        print(f'\n{obj} имеет PushButtons:') #
        print(* [[btn.text(), btn.objectName()]  for btn in btns], sep='\n')
        print(f'\n{obj} имеет LineEdits:') #
        print(* [[lin.text(), lin.objectName()]  for lin in lins], sep='\n')

        _obj = self.parent.settings_dict[obj]                            # !!!
        print(f'{_obj.findChild(QLineEdit, "fio_edit_set_2").text()}')                 

    def delete_groupBox(self, obj):                                      # !!!
        msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(None, 
            "Внимание подтвердите удаление объекта!", 
            f"Вы действительно хотите удалить '{obj}' ?",  
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel)

        if msgBox == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel:
            return
            
        _obj = self.parent.settings_dict[obj]
        _obj.deleteLater()                               
        self.parent.settings_dict.pop(obj)              

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def click_btn_save(self, obj):                                     # !!!
# ?        num_obj = obj_2[9:]
# ?        otv_f = f'fio_edit_set_{num_obj}'
# ?        в этой переменной я пытаюсь узнать занчение, кот.находится в lineEdit
# ?        otv_fio = otv_f.text()    

        _obj = self.parent.settings_dict[obj] 
        otv_fio = _obj.findChild(QLineEdit, "fio_edit_set_2").text()

        print(f'otv_fio = {otv_fio}')         
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class MainWindow(QDialog, Main_Ui):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)                   
        
        self.setting_num = 0                    
        self.settings_dict = {}                 
                
        self.settings_hm.clicked.connect(self.go_setting)

        self.settings = Settings_l(self)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10, self.add_settings) 

    def add_settings(self):
        widget.addWidget(self.settings) 

    def go_setting(self):
        widget.setCurrentIndex(1)      


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    widget = QStackedWidget()
    widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
    widget.resize(686, 580)
    widget.setWindowTitle('Forwork')
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Если очень хочется, то такое можно сделать в Питоне примерно так:

```
otv_f = globals()[f'fio_edit_set_{num_obj}']
```

Но вы тут явно забиваете гвозди микроскопом, вам нужно пересмотреть структуру данных и то, как вы с ними работаете.